# Java: necessity of private variables and return methods

Tags: java, variables, methods, private

In code I've seen, some people often use private variables, e.g.

```
private static int number;
```

And they usually have access methods such as

```
public static int returnNumber(){

    return number;

}
```

But my question is, what's the point? The way I do it is this

```
int number;
```

Followed by this when I need to access it

```
int numberToBeAssigned = someClass.number;
```

instead of

```
int numberToBeAssigned = someClass.getNumber();
```

To me it seems impractical to use accessor methods and private variables, I know what they do, the private variables are only allowed to be accessed by the class in which they are located. I just don't see the necessity for them, when you can just as easily instantialize the class and call upon its member variable when you need it. I'm obviously wrong in my logic, but I would like someone to give a clear example on how private variables along with accessor methods can be utilized.

Thank you

Comment: This is going be closed as "not constructive" real quickly, but let me just say that you're not *wrong*, you just have probably never worked on anything really *big*. `private` lets you have guaranteed "read-only variables", and without those, debugging can be an unmitigated nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The point of accessors like this is to allow you to redesign the implementation without breaking all the rest of your code.  For example, what if you decide later on that `number` should come from a file?  Or should be moved to another class?

If you've limited access to go through an accessor, then you can make changes like these and you only have to change the accessor -- you don't have to change all the other code that depends on it.

Comment: Excellent! That makes much more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

This is all about encapsulation. Public fields let any ol' class come along and change your values, and possibly break your invariants. If you have just a `public int foo`, anyone can set it. If it's a `private int foo` and you provide a getter, people can only get it. If you provide a getter and setter, then they can do both, *but* you still have control over it; you can reject a change that would break assumptions the class has to (or wants to) make.

It could be that you don't have any such assumptions in this class right now, but a) you may have some in the future and b) other classes do have those assumptions, and therefore need to protected their private fields, and it's nice to have a consistent way of accessing data (not fields in some cases, getters and setters in others).

Really though, this is about basic OO principles: your class isn't just a blob of state, it's a *something* which has properties and actions -- and under the hood has state to reflect those actions. So for instance, when you ask for a `List`'s `length()`, you don't conceptually care whether that's reported back as a cached value or whether the `List` iterated over its elements and counted them; you just want its length.

Which brings us to the last big point (at least in this answer :) ), which is that a getter and setter can be overriden to take advantage of inheritance, while a field cannot.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a perspective from [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encapsulation_%28object-oriented_programming%29):

> Hiding the internals of the object protects its integrity by preventing users from setting the internal data of the component into an invalid or inconsistent state. A benefit of encapsulation is that it can reduce system complexity, and thus increases robustness, by allowing the developer to limit the interdependencies between software components.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of books written on these issues, the answer can't really be fully explained in a stackoverflow answer format. Actually, it is very important. Long story short, the less assessors you provide in your code, the more opportunities you have to change it while refactoring, without damaging code of those, who use it. Your code becomes clean and robust, you may achieve a better level of immutability, you can make better architectural decision.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
You want to minimize unwanted interactions by publishing as little of a component as is necessary for it to still do its part and by enforcing that the component behaves in the application as closely as possible as it behaves in isolation (where it can easily be tested).

Longer answer:
A type's methods represent its contract while its variables represent its state. Any non-trivial type will contain multiple member variables, with their own interrelated states. As the fonctionality offered by that type (its contract) evolves (new or expanded features, bug fixes), the programmer has to keep in mind all those relations to make sure that the existing behavior does not get broken.

A well-proven way to achieve that is to write Unit Tests, but those only validate the type in isolation. By minimizing the exposition of a type's state and restricting it to well-understood and planned operations, the programmer attempts to minimize disruptions of the model that he or she was able to test.

Contrarily, if external components have ways to access the component state beyond those planned for by the designer of that type, it's easy for them to inadvertently break its behavior. And interactions between components are exponential: in my experience, once a program comprehends more than 20,000 lines of code, is authored by multiple developers each specialized in separate modules, and goes through multiple revisions, no-one will have a perfect idea of the whole code anymore.

A lot of books and articles have been written on the topic, and I'm sure they will be more eloquent and convincing than I can be. For the general best practices in Java, I highly recommend Josh Bloch's Effective Java (2nd edition).